# Is it possible to find elementary integral of $\frac{\arcsin x}{x}$?

Tags: integration

How could I possibly indefinite integral:
$$
\int{\arcsin\left(x\right) \over x}\,{\rm d}x
$$
using elementary functions? If it is impossible to integrate using elementary functions, Is there any way to find the definite integral in the range
$\left[0,\pi/2\right]$ ?. If so please teach me how to find it.

Comment: An obvious thing to try is to substitute $x = \sin \theta$. Who knows if it will actually help, but it's an obvious thing to try.

Comment: 0 to $\pi/2$? do you mean $0$ to $1$ Since you have a arcsin in there?

Comment: See [trigonometric integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral), [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: @Lucian $\arcsin$ is undefined at $\pi/2$ though?

Comment: I assume you meant to say $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,\pi/2]$ since we're dealing with $\arcsin$ instead of $\sin$.

Comment: @Lucian yes I assumed that too. OP made a typo probably.Or he meant to say $\sin(\pi/2)$ instead of *just* $\pi/2$.

Comment: [*Inverse tangent integral*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As, Hurkyl suggests, substitute $x=\sin\theta$. I am  also assuming that you in fact intended the limits to be $0$ and $1$ since, $\arcsin$ is undefined for $\pi/2$. With some simple manipulations, the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\,dx$$

Substitute, $t=\ln\sin(x)\implies dt=\cos(x)\,dx/\sin(x)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 x\,dt \text{ where $x = \arcsin(e^t)$}$$

Integrating by parts, i.e, applying $\int v\,du = uv - \int udv$

$$\lbrack x\ln(\sin x)\rbrack_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx$$

Both of these functions are elementary and solvable and left as an exercise to the reader. The answer is $\large \frac{\pi\ln(2)}{2}$

---

**EDIT:** I assumed that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x)dx$ would be familiar to most readers. I have since edited the answer to show the work here.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx$$

as noted in my comment. Adding the LHS to both sides,

$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\right)\,dx$$

$$2I = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin(2x)\right) -\ln(2)\,dx$$

$$2I = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin(2x)\right)\,dx -\pi\ln(2)/2$$

$$2I = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{\ln\left(\sin(u)\right)}{2}\,du -\pi\ln(2)/2$$

By symmetry arguments, $\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))\,dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))\,dx$

$$2I = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin(u)\right)\,du -\pi\ln(2)/2$$

$$2I = I - \pi\ln(2)/2$$

$$I =  - \pi\ln(2)/2$$

Comment: If you are saying $\int\log(\sin x)\,dx$ is an elementary function, I don't think that's right.

Comment: @GerryMyerson elementary in the sense trivial. At least to me, since I guess I have seen in it before. You seem to have a LOT of rep, so feel free to edit that bit into my answer. It can be solved using the property $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos x)\,dx$$ since, $$\int_0^af(x)\,dx = \int_0^af(a-x)dx$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't mean trivial in the usual sense. I just meant that our professor usually allows us to just right that particular integral's value instead of showing our work if it comes up somewhere in our answer.

Comment: In the worst case, you can expand the integrand as an infinite Taylor series and integrate it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that isn't necessary at all. There is a much simpler version to do that here.

Comment: @Sabyasachi. I am addressing the problem of the integral between bounds which could differ from $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh. But how? Isn't $\arcsin$ undefined for above x=1? I might not know about a wider definition though.

Comment: @Sabyasachi. Sorry, I was meaning $1$ and not $\pi/2$. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh. ok. :) yes that would be messy though. I am not willing to get into it. feel free to post it as a separate answer.

Comment: I'll give you "well-known", but not "trivial".

Comment: @GerryMyerson As I said, my usage of "trivial" wasn't the usual one, I meant to say "this is easy, give it a shot yourself"

Comment: I wouldn't even say it was easy, for someone who had never seen it before.

Comment: @GerryMyerson agreed yes. I just left is as exercise, although after your suggestion, I edited the rest into my answer for the sake of a complete solution.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I got some trouble with the part [xln(sinx)]0 to pi/2 because I think 0*ln(sin0) is an indeterminate form of 0*infinity, or does 0*infinity = 0 ?

Comment: @Mike no $0*\infty \ne 0$. You can take limits? In *this* case it evaluates to 0 though.

Comment: You can use L'hospital here, but as a rule of thumb, ln(x) is asymptotically lower than x, so x becomes 0 "faster" than ln(x) becomes $-\infty$.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I don't get the point there, could it be evaluated by limits?

Comment: @Mike yes. You can evaluate the limit of the indeterminate form. L'hospital.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a antiderivative in terms of the dilogarithm.

I'm going to use the fact that $$\int_{0}^{z} f(x) \cot(x) \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{z} f(x) \sin(2nx) \ dx$$

and the fact that for $0 < x < 2 \pi,$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos kx}{k} = - \log \left( 2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \right)$$

Then

$$\int_{0}^{z} \frac{\arcsin x}{x} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\arcsin z} u \cot u \ du =$$

$$= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\arcsin z} x \sin (2nx) \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{\sin (2nx)}{4n^{2}}  - \frac{z \cos (2nx)}{2n} \Big) \Big|^{\arcsin z}_{0}$$

$$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2n \arcsin z)}{2n^{2}} - \arcsin(z)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \cos (2n \arcsin z)}{n}  $$

$$ =  \frac{1}{2} \text{Im} \ \text{Li}_{2} \left(e^{2i \arcsin z} \right) + \arcsin(z) \log(2z)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\Lambda \in {\mathbb R}}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x&=
\sgn\pars{\Lambda}\int_{0}^{\verts{\Lambda}}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\arcsin\pars{\Lambda}\ln\pars{\verts{\Lambda}} -
\sgn\pars{\Lambda}\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\verts{\Lambda}}\ln\pars{x}\,{1 \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}\,\dd x}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{x \equiv t^{1/2}\quad\imp\quad t = x^{2}}$
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\verts{\Lambda}}\ln\pars{x}\,{1 \over \root{1 - x^{2}}}
> \,\dd x}=
> \int_{0}^{\Lambda^{2}}\ln\pars{t^{1/2}}\,
> {1 \over \root{1 - \pars{t^{1/2}}^{2}}}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over 4}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\Lambda^{2}}t^{\mu}
> \pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
> ={1 \over 4}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{{\rm B}_{\Lambda^{2}}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2}}{\mu}
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{{\rm B}_{z}\pars{a,b}}$ is the
>   [Incomplete Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).
>   By replacing in $\pars{1}$:
>   $$
> \color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =\arcsin\pars{\Lambda}\ln\pars{\verts{\Lambda}} - {1 \over 4}\,\sgn\pars{\Lambda}
> \lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{{\rm B}_{\Lambda^{2}}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2}}{\mu}}
> $$

For the particular cases $\ds{\Lambda = \pm 1}$,
$\ds{{\rm B}_{\Lambda^{2}}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2} = {\rm B}_{1}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2}
={\rm B}\pars{\mu + 1,1/2}}$ where $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{a,b}}$ is the
[Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html). Also,
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{a,b} = \Gamma\pars{a}\Gamma\pars{b}/\Gamma\pars{a + b}}$.
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
[Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

Then,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pm 1}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
&=\mp\,{1 \over 4}\lim_{\mu \to -1/2}\totald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}
\\[3mm]&=\mp\,{1 \over 4}\,\Gamma\pars{\half}\bracks{%
{\Gamma\pars{1/2}\Psi\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
-{\Gamma\pars{1/2}\Psi\pars{1} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}}
\\[3mm]&=\mp\,{1 \over 4}\,\Gamma^{2}\pars{\half}\bracks{\Psi\pars{\half} - \Psi\pars{1}}
\end{align}
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{1/2} = \root{\pi}}$. $\ds{\Psi\pars{1/2} = -\gamma - 2\ln\pars{2}.\ \Psi\pars{1} = -\gamma}$.
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ and $\ds{\gamma}$ are the *Digamma Function* and 
the *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*, respectively. See
[this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html). Then,
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pm 1}{\arcsin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
=
\pm\,\half\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}
$$

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Just to point out clearly the main results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, I suggested to develop the integrand as an infinite Taylor expansion to be integrated later. Doing so, I obtained as a result 
$$\int \frac{\arcsin x}{x}\,dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{4^{-n} (2 n)!}{(2 n+1)^2 (n!)^2} x^{2 n+1}$$ which has been later found to be the development of an hypergeometric function. So, as a final result, $$\int \frac{\arcsin x}{x}\,dx=x \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};x^2\right)$$ For sure, this result is not expressed on the basis of elementary functions but it is analytical.

If the hypergeometric function cannot be used for any reason, the Taylor expansion can be efficiently used since it converges very quickly. As an example $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arcsin x}{x} \ dx$$ is computed iwth a relative error of less than $0.1$% adding $20$ terms and this is probably more than sufficient for most engineering calculations.

What is interesting is that this approach could be used for the calculation of
$$\int \frac{\arcsin x^a}{x^b}\,dx $$ where $a$ and $b$ could be any numbers.